# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated by using exec

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that takes a *lowerBound* and *lowerBound* of numbers and use another executable to find primes in this space. I want to use some sort of exec function for that.

My code so far:

```c
{

    char variables[20];
    char* args[2];

    snprintf(variables, 20, " %d %d", lb, ub);      // Get variables

    strcpy(args[0], "./Code4Primes/prime1");    // first arg is the path to the executable
    args[1] = NULL;

    strcat(args[0], variables);       // Append variables string to arguments

    execv(args[0], args);     // Executing

}
```

I get a

> *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

error and I have not found any useful answer yet. I should point out that I use fork before this code.

Comment: Doesn't look like `args[0]` is assigned to anything before you write to the place it points using `strcpy`.

Comment: Why are you using `args[0]` as a temporary string? What do you think happen if the string is not big enough? As a general rule, don't use `argv` strings as destinations.

Comment: This also isn't how `execv` works.  Instead of executing `./Code4Primes/prime1` with arguments like `1234` and  `2345`, you are executing a file with the unlikely space-containing name of `./Code4Primes/prime1 1234 2345` with no arguments.  You really want the two numeric strings in `args[1]` and `args[2]` with `args[3] = NULL`.

Comment: All good guys, thanks a lot for the comments